# When can "$j: V \rightarrow M$ is an elementary embedding" be defined in ZF?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

This regards elementary embeddings of inner models of set theory.

It seems that it is in general "stated" via an axiom schema each member of which states that the class function is elementary with respect to a specific formula.

However, for certain elementary embeddings — namely those induced by measurable cardinals — it can be stated in a single sentence that the embedding is elementary by stating it is induced by a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$ for some $\kappa$. Thus the proper axiom schema is in some cases equivalent to a single sentence.

When is this the case? Do there exist nontrivial elementary embeddings $j$ such that there is no sentence equivalent to "the class function $j$ is an elementary embedding"?

Comment: It's a standard result that the claim for $\Sigma_1$ formulas implies the $\Sigma_n$ instances for each $n$ (see Kanamori prop. 5.1). And it doesn't rely on Choice.

Comment: Regarding your last question. It certainly is possible that such elementary embeddings exist. In fact: If there is any nontrivial elementary embedding $j \colon V \to M$, then $j \restriction L \colon L \to L$  is nontrivial and elementary and there is no formula $\phi$ such that $\{(x,y) \mid L \models \phi(x,y) \}=j$, i.e. $L$ can't define this embedding. So, living in $L$, $j \restriction L$ is such an example. Similarly, $j$ can exist in a forcing extension of $V$ - and remain to be undefinable in $V$.

Comment: On the other hand, every large cardinal concept that I know of can be formulated in terms of set sized (long) extenders and their associated ultrapowers - giving a solid way to formalize these concepts within ZFC.

Answer (score 1):

While not a complete answer, there is a paper by Mitchell Spector which deals with ultrapowers in $\sf ZF$.

> *Mitchell Spector*, [**Ultrapowers without the axiom of choice**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2274614), *J. Symbolic Logic* **53** (1988), no. 4, 1208--1219.

There he proves (Theorem 1), quite nicely, that the following are equivalent for an ultrapower embedding $j\colon\mathfrak M\to\mathfrak M^I/U$, where $I$ is some index set and $U$ is an ultrafilter on $I$, in $\frak M$:

1. In $\frak M$, if $f$ is a function on $I$, such that $f(x)\neq\varnothing$ $U$-a.e., then there is some $g$ such that $g(x)\in f(x)$ $U$-a.e.
2. Los theorem for the ultrapower embedding holds.
3. The embedding is elementary.
4. $\frak M$ and $\mathfrak M^I/U$ are elementarily equivalent.
5. $\mathfrak M^I/U$ satisfies the axiom of extensionality.
6. There is some $d\in\mathfrak M^I/U$, such that $\mathfrak M\models\forall x\forall y((y\in x\leftrightarrow y\in d)\rightarrow x=d)$.

The proof is quite simple, as all the forward implications are trivial. So it only remains to prove $6\implies 1$, and the proof is not hard to follow. (I was told the rest of the papers might contain mistakes, but this proof is quite simple and seems to be correct.)

---

So while I can't quite give you a complete answer, it seems that at least something can be said on ultrapower embeddings. It also means that if the axiom of choice for *well-ordered families* holds, then ultrapowers with measurable cardinals should be possible.

Comment: Thank you. This seems interesting in its own right. However, what I was getting at is: Is there a single sentence that is equivalent to the proper axiom schema stating the $j$ is an elementary embedding? I would guess no, but I would like to see a proof of this.

Comment: (By talking about elementary embeddings induced by ultrapowers in my question, I was merely pointing out that in certain cases the proper axiom schema is equivalent to a single sentence.)

Comment: Well, in general not every embedding is given by an ultrafilter in ZFC either. But the point is that in ZF at least for ultrapowers you can say something like "there is choice $U$-a.e. and such and such" as you would have in ZFC.

Comment: Oh, I see, you interpreted my question as going from ZFC to ZF. This was not the intent, but it's noteworthy nonetheless. Yes, not every embedding is given by an ultrafilter, and I was asking about if for those embeddings elementarity can be stated with a single sentence like they can for ultrafilter embeddings. In fact, can there even exist a definable embedding not generated by an ultrafilter, or is it necessary to add a unary predicate denoting $j$ to the language of set theory, alongside the axiom schema stating it's an embedding?

Comment: If so, I'm really not fond of the way strong cardinals, for instance, cannot be stated in the language of set theory, but rather require LST enhanced with a unary predicate. It just seems like it's not even set theory anymore if it's not even over the language of set theory.

Comment: Strong cardinals have associated extenders. It's fine.